# Temporarily disabled updating view after viewmodel changed in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

In my knockout code first I am updating the view model then I am calling a heavy duty API based on that update . But I want my view will be updated after in API call completed how to do that

Code is like this

```
 for (var i = 0; i < self.AppEntityErrorRequestAttributes().length; i++)
            self.AppEntityActionRequestAttributes.push(self.AppEntityErrorRequestAttributes()[i]); 
// Dont want to update view
 var validationStatus = FilterValidation(self);
        //debugger;
        //var filterData = self.AppEntityErrorRequestAttributes();
        //filterData = ko.toJSON(self.AppEntityErrorRequestAttributes());
        if (validationStatus == false) {
            toastr.error("You cannot save filter with a blank key", 'Sorry!');
        }
        else {
            ajaxRequest("POST", baseUrl + 'api/' + controller + "save/", self)
                 .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                     $(location).attr('href', baseUrl + controller + "?entityId=" + entityId);
                for (var i = 0; i < self.AppEntityErrorRequestAttributes().length; i++)
                            self.AppEntityActionRequestAttributes.pop(self.AppEntityErrorRequestAttributes()[i]);

                  // Now want to update view 

                 });
        }
```

Comment: Share some code

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran just updated the code

Comment: I dont understant whats wrong with your code?. You can update the model in done callback right

Comment: no there is nothing wrong in my code but I just want to update the view after certain point. See the comments in the code snippet

Comment: is `var validationStatus = FilterValidation(self);` this line updates the model?

Comment: This lines  updates the model                                                                                              for (var i = 0; i < self.AppEntityErrorRequestAttributes().length; i++)
            self.AppEntityActionRequestAttributes.push(self.AppEntityErrorRequestAttributes()[i]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130465/discussion-between-jaganathan-bantheswaran-and-utpal).

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

```js
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
 var self = this;
  var ajaxFinished = ko.observable(false);

 $.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
   data: '',
   success: function() {
     ajaxFinished(true);
   },
   fail: function() {
   alert('fail');
   },
   error: function() {
   alert('error');
   }
 });
 
 ajaxFinished.subscribe(function() {
  //do something
   alert('ajax finished');
 });
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/madJohn/jdeokaa6/12/)